# Referencing a delegate via another delegate in C#

Tags: c#

Suppose that my namespace has 2 delegates:

```
public delegate void D1(string s);
public delegate void D2(string s);
```

They are implemented in a static class StClass like this:

```
public static D1 myD1 { get; set; }
public static D2 myD2 { get; set; }
```

In each instance of a separate non-static class MyClass I would like to include a delegate that points to one of the 2 static delegates as determined by the constructor. So I would have:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public delegate void D(string s);
   public D myD { get; set; }
   
   public MyClass()
   {
      if()
      {
         myD = StClass.myD1 //this assignment won't work
      }
      else
      {
         myD = StClass.myD2
      }
}
```

I get that I cannot directly link myD to myD1 or myD2 the way it's shown above because from the compiler's standpoint they are instances of different delegate types, but I figure since they all share the same signature there should be a simple way to achieve this. What am I missing?

Comment: Why have you declared multiple delegate types? They have the same signature. In fact, you could use `Action<string>` and not declare any delegate types at all.

Comment: You can always just proxy: myD = s => StClass.myD1 (s)

Comment: Proxying like that is different, though. If `StClass.myD1` changes, `myD` is affected. That differs from the copy semantics OP is attempting to use (intentionally or not).

Comment: As an aside, it's really useful if you could present full code that's working for everything other than where you've got a problem - currently you're missing semi-colons, if conditions, a closing brace, the `StClass` declaration etc... so anyone who wants to test a solution has to do all of that separately. Ideally, a question should contain the code ready to copy/paste/compile - and follow .NET naming conventions at the same time.

Comment: @WiktorZychla: Thanks, I've included that option in my answer, along with the difference between using a lambda and other options.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, it would probably be *better* to avoid declaring multiple delegate types with the same signature like this.

However, if you absolutely have to, you can convert them like this:

```cs
myD = new D(StClass.myD1);
```

Note that this uses *the value of `StClass.myD1` at the time of assignment*. If you want to dynamically observe any changes in `StClass.myD1`, you could use a lambda expression instead:

```cs
myD = s => StClass.myD1(s);
```

This will evaluate the `StClass.myD1` property on each invocation.

Comment: Alternatively, `myD = StClass.myD1.Invoke` with an implicit method-group conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You start by saying *"Suppose that my namespace has 2 delegates:"*

```
public delegate void D1(string s);
public delegate void D2(string s);
```

But, that's not what you are showing.  You are showing the declaration of two, *different* **Delegate Types**.  You still haven't declared a delegate yet.

Then, within your class, you declare a third delegate type, and an instance of that type:

```
public delegate void D(string s);
public D myD { get; set; }
```

Now you start trying to assign delegates of one type to another.  That's never going to work; two delegate types, even if their definition completely agrees, remain distinct types.  Somewhere, @EricLippert has a blog entry that explains this in detail (but, after a quick search, I can't find it).  The pair of types that show this that most C# programmers are familiar with (and curse at) are:

```
delegate bool Predicate<in T>(T obj);
```

and

```
Func<T, bool>
```

The latter is used for the `IEnumerable<T>.Where()` extension method, while the former is used in methods like `List<T>.FindAll()`.  *Grrrr*

The solution, as others have pointed out, is to use a single delegate type.  Both the generic `Action` and `Func` delegates have been around for nearly forever now.  I rarely define delegate types anymore, instead relying on those two types.